# Prevent a user from getting logged out on page refresh

Tags: php, session

I use nuBuilder 4. When a user is logged in and refreshes the page **(e.g. by hitting F5)** he gets logged out.
I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481888/does-refreshing-a-page-destroy-php-sessions) that `session_start();` needs to be at the very beginning of the code. But that didn't help.

`index.php`  starts with this code:

> (https://github.com/steven-copley/nubuilder4/blob/master/index.php)

```
<?php   
    require_once('nuchoosesetup.php');
    require_once('nuindexlibs.php');
    if ( !$_SESSION['nubuilder_session_data']['PLUGIN'] ) {
        require_once('nustandalonesetuplibs.php'); 
        nuStandaloneImportNewDB();
    }
    if ( $_SESSION['nubuilder_session_data']['PLUGIN'] && !isset($_SESSION['nubuilder_session_data']['SESSION_ID']) ) {
                require_once('nuwordpresssetuplibs.php');
        nuCheckWPUser();
        }
    require_once('nusystemupdatelibs.php');
    nuMigrateSQL();
?>
```

Unfortunately I don't know PHP sessions so well and don't know where to change what. I'm grateful for hints.

Comment: your `session_start` needs to be before the call to `$_SESSION`

Comment: Not sure where/in which file to add it. I added it to nuprocesslogins.php and nusession.php  but no success there.

Comment: NuSoftware runs a own support forum for this software, where you definitively get a better help for you problem as here.
https://forums.nubuilder.com/

Comment: You have not included `nuprocesslogins.php` or `nusession.php` in the code you have shown... on every page you access `$_SESSION` you need to have an include that has `session_start()` before the `$_SESSION` statement

Comment: I added session_start(); in all php files. It's still logging me out. I have no idea what else could be done.

Comment: you might have done so, but the example you have shown will not work, for the reason i wrote...

Comment: Even if I include session_start(); and require_once('nuprocesslogins.php');
require_once('nusession.php'); in index.php, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. I had similar problem with calling session.

```
if (!session_id()) {

  session_start();

} else {

  // your code

}
```

Comment: I've tried it with this code: if (!isset($_SESSION['nubuilder_session_data']['SESSION_ID']) ) {
  session_start();
} else {
  // code
}
but then, I blank page is returned (without any errors in the dev. console)